# Prove the binomial identity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots , n$,  and for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ we have: $$ {n \choose k} = {{n-1} \choose {k-1}} + {{n-1} \choose k}$$

I know that there are a lot of solutions for the Newton's equal but I'm really sure what to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> An interesting one is given by the $\ds{Binomial\ Integral\ Representation}$
>   $$
> {a \choose b} = \oint_{\verts{z} = R}{\pars{1 + z}^{a} \over z^{b + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,,\qquad b \in \mathbb{Z}
> $$
>   $\ds{R > 0}$ is chosen such that the $\ds{\pars{1 + z}^{a}}$-expansion, in powers of $\ds{z}$, converges.

Namely,
\begin{align}
{n \choose k} & = \oint_{\verts{z} = R}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=
\oint_{\verts{z} = R}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1}\pars{1 + z} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z} = R}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} +
\oint_{\verts{z} = R}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z^{k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\bbx{\ds{{n - 1 \choose k} + {n - 1 \choose k - 1}}}\,,\qquad
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$LHS={n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$
$$RHS={n-1\choose k-1}+{n-1\choose k}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!k!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!(k-1)!}\left[\frac{1}{n-k}+\frac1k\right]=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!(k-1)!}\left[\frac{n}{(n-k)k}\right]=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}=LHS$$

Answer (score 1):

You have a total of $n$ objects. You have two possible techniques to choose a $k$-set:

**Method 1:** Choose $k$ elements from the $n$ objects directly.  This gives the count on the LHS.

**Method 2:** Single out an arbitrary element $a$.  Now there are the $k$-sets containing $a$ (by taking $k-1$ of the remaining $n-1$ elements), and there are the $k$-sets not containing $a$ (by taking $k$ of the remaining $n-1$ elements). This gives the count on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

The formula also reflects
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{n-1}(1+x)
\end{align*}

> Indeed, using $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in an expression we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{n}{k}&=[x^k](1+x)^n\\
> &=[x^k](1+x)^{n-1}(1+x)\\
> &=[x^k](1+x)^{n-1}+[x^k]x(1+x)^{n-1}\\
> &=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}
> \end{align*}

Here we use $[x^k]xA(x)=[x^{k-1}]A(x)$.